# print css A6 on A4 paper

Tags: css, printing

I have a website generating a DIN A6 page with 300dpi as png (for reference let's name it tag.png). I now am trying to extract only this image of a page and print it in A6 format on a A4 sheet of paper via a print.css.
Howsoever all my tries have failed and I get a upscaled version of my .png.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Also, is DIN A3 the same as ISO A3?

Comment: "is DIN A3 the same as ISO A3?" Yes, they are. The DIN A4 is a historical term, but most Germans still use it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing the point, but why not just apply the A6 dimensions to the image in your print css?

```
style="width:105mm;height:148mm"
```